# Terminate an array input taking when input is -1 without using break?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, input, break

I am taking input in an array of length 100 using scanf in a loop. After 20 numbers, if I enter -1, I want the loop to exit, i.e finish taking input and continue with the rest of the program. I am doing something like this

```
for(i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &input[i]);
    if(input[i] == -1)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

I heard, it is bad practice to use break statements even though this code works perfectly fine. So I was wondering what is a more efficient way to end the loop when `-1` is entered. I tried

```
for(i=0;scanf("%d",&input[i])!=-1;i++)
```

also

```
fori(i=0;i<100;i++){
    do
{scanf("%d", &input[i]);
}while(input[i]!=-1
}
```

Neither of these don't work

Comment: You don't check the value returned by `scanf()`. What if the user enters `q`?

Comment: *"I heard, it is bad practice to use break statements even though this code works perfectly fine."* Whoever said that was wrong. `break` is perfectly valid for the task it was made for. Just use it with care, just like everything else in C.

Comment: @DavidBowling We are not going to be dealing with `char` for this

Comment: @user694733 my professor said this, I really wan't to argue with him about this at the end of the semester, break has always worked perfectly fine for me.

Comment: @SanMo -- but the posted code will likely lead to undefined behavior if the user fails to cooperate by providing non-numeric input. In such cases nothing is stored in `input[]`.

Comment: `break` is a kind of cleaner goto. Probably your professor wants you to use only loop conditions - like `end=0 ; for(... ; !end && ... ; ...) if (...) end=1; else ...`

Comment: Also, the question is a bit terse in that it doesn't mention if  `-1` is an acceptable value in the array.

Comment: @DavidBowling The code will not be tested for anything other than `int` inputs. So input type validation is not required in this case.

Comment: @SanMo -- the point is, you should _always_ check the return value of `scanf()` family functions, and in fact you should always check the return value from any function that returns a meaningful value. User input should never be trusted, and should always be considered as malicious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second expression of the `for` loop is a free-form boolean expression. In *this* case you *could* add your condition there. However in this case it wouldn't look exactly nice. For example

```
for(i=0; i < 100 && (i < 1 || input[i - 1] != -1); i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &input[i]);
}
```

I.e. if we have already input one value, check the value and that must be inequal to `-1` for the loop to continue

Another would be to use a synthetic flag variable:

```
int loop_again = 1;
for (i = 0; loop_again && i < 100; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &input[i]);
    if(input[i] == -1)
    {
        loop_again = 0;
    }
}
```

All in all, these both look way uglier than just using the `break` statement for the very thing that it was invented for.

Note that you also should check the return value of `scanf` itself!

Comment: `&& i >= 1 && ` makes no sense as you initalize `i=0`.

Comment: Agreed, I would much rather use the break statement, but apparently I have satan for instructor who takes off quite a lot of points for using codes HE THINKS is wrong.

Comment: @user694733 oops, it is so contrived I got it wrong

Comment: @SanMo then the lesson is to do the right thing and take less points for it!

Answer (score 1):

> it is bad practice to use `break` statements

As Ancient Greeks said, "Pan Metron Ariston", which means that everything that is used with balance is great. This applies here too, and your code as is, is good to go. The only thing to be worried about is *not checking the return value* of `scanf()`.

Now if you really insist on changing your approach, then please refer to Haapala's answer, we got there first.

Comment: I am so going to use that pan metron ariston :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `while` loop and check for `-1` in the input in the loop conditional. Note that you should *always* check the value returned by `scanf()`. In the posted code, non-numeric input results in no value being stored in `input[]`; this may lead to undefined behavior later if the code attempts to use an indeterminate value.

Here is an example. Note that the loop conditional first checks whether the array index has grown too large, then checks the return value from `scanf()` to be sure that a number was entered, then checks to see if `-1` was entered. In the case of non-numeric input, the loop is terminated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define INPUT_SZ  100

int main(void)
{
    int input[INPUT_SZ];
    size_t i = 0;

    while (i < INPUT_SZ && scanf("%d", &input[i]) == 1 && input[i] != -1) {
        ++i;
    }

    puts("You entered:");
    for (size_t j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        printf("%d\n", input[j]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample interaction:

```
2 4 6 8 -1
You entered:
2
4
6
8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change the value of counter variable to max, then it'll automatically come out of loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define MAX 10

int main()
{
    int ar[MAX], i, count;
    for(i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &ar[i]);
        if(ar[i]==-1)
        {
            count=i--;         //this is your new MAX. Not mandatory but will be useful if you need to access array elements
            i=MAX;
        }
    }

    //printing array
    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        printf("Element %d: %d\t", i+1, ar[i]);    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How is this any better than using `break`? It is more widely considered bad practice to modify loop counters within the body of a `for` loop than it is to use the keyword `break` for what it was designed for.

Comment: Apologies. Didn't knew that. Thought it would be a good alternative. Thanks for correcting :)

Comment: Not wrong, just not particularly good style. The only problem I see is a typo: `return;` --> `return 0;`. Note that modification of the loop variable `i` makes it more difficult to reason about the code than necessary. Consider the case when the user enters `-1` as the first entry. What is the value of `i` at various places in the code? What is the value of `count`? Note that `ar[-1]` would lead to undefined behavior, a problem another answer on this page has. Your code seems to escape _this_ problem, but it is less obvious that it should work correctly because `i` is modified in 3 places.

Answer (score -1):

Use a `do-while` loop

```
int i=0;
do{
if(scanf("%d", &input[i++]) != 1)
{
   if(i>0)
      --i; // Decrementing i if an integer is not provided
   int ch;
   while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) // Wasting the buffer
   ;   
}
}while(input[i-1] != -1 && i<=99);
```

Comment: I see two immediate problems here. 1) if the user enters, e.g. a letter, the letter stays in the input stream and an infinite loop is entered. 2) if the user enters a letter for the first input, `input[i-1]` --> `input[-1]`, which is undefined behavior due to out of bounds array access.

Comment: @DavidBowling I overlooked those scenarios. Thank you.

Comment: `i=i==0?i:i--;` may lead to undefined behavior with the path: `i = i--;`. What about: `if (i > 0) { --i; }`? But, still if the user enters a letter as the first input, `i` will be `0` in the conditional, giving `while(input[-1] != -1 && i<=99);`, and undefined behavior. Also, `char ch` --> `int ch`, since `getchar()` returns an `int`, and a `char` may not be able to hold the value of `EOF`.